# Row Consolidation using pivot table or transpose

Tags: excel, pivot-table, transpose

I'm not sure if transpose or pivot table is the best method to do this but please help if you can.
I want to convert multiple columns in excel into rows but duplicate the first column for a possible unknown number of columns the highest I know has 196 different columns. I tired normal transpose but that doesn't keep the relationship to A it just converts it to columns without the importance of element A. I also need to do this many different times that's why transpose isn't quite right.

The transformation would look something like this

---

with each letter being associated with a row and in this case, element b has four columns A has 3 and C only has 2

A  string 1     String 2      String 3
B  String 4     String 5      String 6     String 7
C  String 8     String 9

then be converted into 2 columns with

A String 1
A String 2
A String 3
B String 4
B String 5
B String 6
B String 7
C String 8
C String 9

Answer (score 0):

Use *Data* > *Get and Transform* (Excel 2016 on), or the Power Query add-in (Excel 2010 and Excel 2013):

1. Select your data.
2. Go to *Data* > *Get Data* > *From Other Sources* > *From Table/Range*.
   [image]
3. Hit *OK* to create a table if your data is not already formatted as one.
4. Once the Power Query editor opens up, select columns 2 through 5:
   [image]
5. Then *Transform* > *Unpivot Columns*. The result in the editor will be:
   [image]
6. Then select the *Attribute* column, and go to *Home* > *Remove Columns*.
7. Now you can load your unpivoted dataset using *Close & Load*.
   [image]